# Whats the namespace of Server.Transfer method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.transfer

I get a red underline under the Server Class:

```
Server.Transfer("~/PostEdit.aspx");
```

The mistake is:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'System.Web.UI.Page' via nested type 'AnswerQuestion.ThreadTable'

AnswerQuestion is the partial class and ThreadTable is a custom class that I made.

Comment: This has nothing to do with namespace. Read the error message. Word by word.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, methods do not have namespaces directly, instead they belong to classes which in turn are classified within namespaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not inside the `Page` instance, so you don't have access to the `Server` property, which is a shortcut to the `Server` property in the HTTP context.

Use the static `Current` property to get the context of the current page:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("~/PostEdit.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Handler
HttpContext.Current.Request.Server.Transfer
```

`Context.Handler` is an instance of an `HttpContext`.

`HttpContext` exposes the CURRENT instance for the request under the `HttpContext.Current` property, however the current context can also be passed in `HTTPHandlers` in the ProcessRequest method:

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: No, `HttpContext.Hander` is an instance of the handler, i.e. the `Page` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly says that you are accessing a non-static member in your class. It has nothing to do with Server.Transfer().

Comment: Server is the non static member accessed

Comment: @Rune FS  - Yes Rune, thats what I am saying.

Comment: "It has nothing to do with Server.Transfer()" I understood that to say it has nothing to do with Server..... To me it has everything to do with Server.... hence my comment